# 'RNG_test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to do PractRand tests in cmd. It works in Ubuntu command line for Windows, but my Python program stops because of "OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error". It is hard or impossible problem to solve (I've tried everything), so I decided to run this test in cmd.

This is what I do:

```
>Mygenerator.py | RNG_test stdin
```

And I get:

```
'RNG_test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

The same RNG_test works in Ubuntu command line, as I wrote before. So problem is with cmd. How to fix it? So far I've changed environment vriables and it didn't help.

Comment: Find the path where RNG_test (.exe? .cmd?) is located, and specify it in full.

Comment: @PeterB D:\PractRand\RNG_test still dosn't work. It is judt "file" type.

Comment: CMD can only run Windows executables with extension `.exe`, scripts with extension `.bat` or `.cmd`, or data files by running the executable that is associated with them. How was your file created? Is it even a Windows executable?

Comment: @PeterB I created this in Ubuntu for Windows with building instructions from here: pcg-random.org/posts/how-to-test-with-practrand.html. Maybe it is not executable. I don't know.

Comment: @PeterB Here they wrote it is possible: "the command line looks like this on linux:
My_RNG | ./RNG_test stdin
Or like this on Windows (from a command prompt):
My_RNG | RNG_test stdin", http://pracrand.sourceforge.net/Tests_overview.txt

Comment: The source code of this library and the example executable `RNG_test` must be compiled, for example, with Microsoft´s Visual Code as written in the poor [installation instructions](http://pracrand.sourceforge.net/installation.txt) for usage in native Windows environment. If the source code files are compiled in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) environment as Linux executable, it can be used only in WSL (Linux) environment.

Comment: @Mofi that make sense. I'll try to compile it with Microsoft´s Visual Code.